# How to escape "at sign" (@) in Invoke-Expression -Command?

Tags: powershell, escaping, powershell-5.0

When I run this command in command-line, it works as expected:

```
C:\>p4 changes @2019/01/16,@now
...
```

But when I use it in powershell script, I can't get it working.

First attempt:

```
PS C:\> Invoke-Expression -Command "p4 changes @2018/01/16, @now"
Invoke-Expression : At line:1 char:25
+ p4 changes @2018/01/16, @now
+                         ~~~~
Splatted variables like '@now' cannot be part of a comma-separated list of arguments.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-Expression -Command "p4 changes @2018/01/16, @now"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SplattingNotPermittedInArgumentList,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
```

Escaping comma (successfully):

```
PS C:\> Invoke-Expression -Command "p4 changes @2018/01/16',' @now"
p4 : Unintelligible revision specification '2018/01/16'.
At line:1 char:1
+ p4 changes @2018/01/16',' @now
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Unintelligible ...n '2018/01/16'.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Now I think the problem is in "at character" ("@") being interpreted on some level. But I've failed to escape it using multiple methods. How to achieve this?

**UPD** Testing your ideas:

Grave Accent:

```
PS C:\> Invoke-Expression -Command "p4 changes `@2018/01/16',' `@now"
p4 : Unintelligible revision specification '2018/01/16'.
At line:1 char:1
+ p4 changes @2018/01/16',' @now
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Unintelligible ...n '2018/01/16'.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Single quote (problem with comma):

```
PS C:\> Invoke-Expression -Command 'p4 changes @2018/01/16, @now'
Invoke-Expression : At line:1 char:25
+ p4 changes @2018/01/16, @now
+                         ~~~~
Splatted variables like '@now' cannot be part of a comma-separated list of arguments.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-Expression -Command 'p4 changes @2018/01/16, @now'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SplattingNotPermittedInArgumentList,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
```

Comment: try using the single `'` quote only instead of double quote `"`

Comment: @Avshalom not working, because I have to escape comma with single quotes. May be there's another way to escape comma and it will work? See update

Comment: Is `p4` an executable? Try `p4 --% changes @2019/01/16,@now`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen yes, it's Perforce client. Your command is not working when I run it in command-line, It advises to check: `p4 -h for usage.`

Comment: Why do you use `Invoke-Expression` at all? `p4 changes '@2019/01/16,@now'` or ``p4 changes @2019/01/16`,@now`` should work?

Comment: @PetSerAl yes, both work, thank you. I was using `Invoke-Expression` because of other, unrelated problem with direct commands in different place of the script, but for this case it's perfectly works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution:

```
$cmd = @'
p4 changes @2018/01/16','@now
'@;    
Invoke-Expression $cmd
```

Answer (score 1):

Stop using double quotes, if you have no expandable content then use single quotes. See documentation for [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules)

Otherwise it's as others have said, use the backtick (`` ` ``).